# Spring Data REST + Hibernate 5 + Jackson LAZY serialization fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-data-rest

I've got 2 entities: User and Address.
The relation is set as follows:

**ADDRESS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Address {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private User user;
```

**USER**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String username;

    (...)

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

Whenever I call `GET http://localhost:8080/api/data/users/{USERNAME}/addresses` for username of user with one or more Address entities, the result is:

STATUS 500

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Id must be assignable to Serializable!: to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.entities.User"
}
```

Also worth mentioning is the fact that even though Spring Data REST generates links:

```
"_links": {
  "self": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/data/addresses/33"
  },
  "address": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/data/addresses/33"
  },
  "user": [
    {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/data/users"
    },
    {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/data/addresses/33/user"
    }
  ]
}
```

the http://localhost:8080/api/data/addresses/33/user link is not working at all. (throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config)

So far I tried changing the LAZY to EAGER FetchingType in Address entity and the behavior then changes as follows:

- I cannot `GET http://localhost:8080/api/data/addresses` (error message is 500 with "Id must be assignable to Serializable!: to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.entities.User")
- I can `GET http://localhost:8080/api/data/users/{USERNAME}/addresses`

Honestly I'm out of ideas right now.

Config files are defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.controllers",
                            "to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.services",
                            "to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.hateoas"
                            })
@Import({JpaConfig.class,
    SecurityConfig.class,
    DataRestConfig.class,
    RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class
})
public class AppConfig {

}

@Configuration
public class DataRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
    config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(
                 RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED
    );
    config.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
    config.setBasePath("/data");
}

@Bean
protected Module module(){
    return new Hibernate5Module();
}

@Override
public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService configurableConversionService){
    configurableConversionService.addConverter(String.class, String[].class, stringToStringArrayConverter());
}

private Converter<String, String[]> stringToStringArrayConverter(){
    return (source) -> StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(source, ";");

}
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages =   "to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.repositories")
public class JpaConfig {
private static Properties getJpaProperties(){
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "couriersystem");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect",  "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans","true");
    return jpaProperties;
}

@Bean
public static LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean asBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    asBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    asBean.setPackagesToScan("to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.entities");
    asBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    asBean.setJpaProperties(getJpaProperties());

    return asBean;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public static DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource bean = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    bean.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    bean.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
    bean.setUsername("dev");
    bean.setPassword("pwd");
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public static JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager asBean = new JpaTransactionManager();
    asBean.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return asBean;
}

@Bean
public static PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public static HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
}
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.controllers")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry){
    registry.removeConvertible(String.class, String[].class);
    registry.addConverter(String.class, String[].class, stringToStringArrayConverter());
}

private Converter<String, String[]> stringToStringArrayConverter(){
    return (source) -> StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(source, ";");
}
}
```

Any help appreciated

**UPDATE**

During the time, I tried to change ID for User class from String to Long.
The issue, however, is still there.Obviously...

**UPDATE 2**

Some interesting log dump (while processing `GET <host>/api/data/addresses`):

```
[DEBUG] 2017-11-06 18:25:01.053 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id must be assignable to Serializable!: to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.entities.User

[DEBUG] 2017-11-06 18:25:01.055 [http-nio-8080-exec-39] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id must be assignable to Serializable!: to.wysylam.couriersystem.api.entities.User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in my code, of course.

I had a `ResourceProcessor<Resource<Address>>` defined and **it took User property for granted**, while in my database there are some Address rows that has no User defined in the relation.

Simple null check solved it, of course.

Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `@JsonSerialize(as = Address.class)` on many-to-one class helped me in my case...

Comment: It didn't work for me, unfortunately... BUt what else could I do wrong here?